# What does '~' at the end of file name mean in Python MVC

Tags: python

Im having a very odd problem. Im trying to install a Python program.

Im using `python setup.py install`

The setup.py file states:

```
install_requires=[
    "Pylons==0.9.7",
```

The setup.py~ file states:

```
install_requires=[
    "Pylons==0.10",
```

This is causing an issue when Im trying to install as the program tries to find Pylons 0.9.7 and install it as a dependency. It then errors with:

```
error: Installed distribution Pylons 0.9.7 conflicts with requirement Pylons==0.10
```

**My question is** what does having the tilde '~' at the end of the file mean? As far as I was aware, it meant that the file is open and being edited somewhere and this is a temp version, is that not correct?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a backup file -- many editors save the previous version of your file under the same name with a `~` appended.

Comment: how to get rid of it? I'm having the same problem when I use vim, it creates 2 versions of the file `file.extension` and `file.extension~`

Comment: That's configured in your editor's settings. Specifics depend on the editor you're using.